# Wrap parameters from Excel in quotes

Tags: json, excel, powershell

We're trying to use PowerShell to populate some JSON files. The parameters are in an Excel sheet, the majority of the JSON parameters get populated with quotes ("") around them. However, there are a few that don't, these are causing the deployment to then fail.

Is there a way of getting the information from the excel and then making sure its wrapped in quotes in the JSON file.

The code is below:

```
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$data = Get-Content -Path "$path\$jsonfile" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$Row = 2
$col = 2  
$data.parameters.client.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Value()
$data.parameters.user.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Offset(1, 0).Value()
$data.parameters.business.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Offset(2, 0).Value()
$data.parameters.dev.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Offset(3, 0).Value()

$data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 | % {
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)
} | Set-Content -Path "$newpath\$JSONFile"
```

Comment: It looks horrid, but you could try `$data.parameters.client.value = '"{0}"' -f $($ws.Cells.Item($Row,$col).Value()).Trim('"')` which should get the value, trim double quotes from the beginning and end, and then insert it into a string that wraps it in double quotes.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json` should handle all quoting for  you, so you shouldn't need to call `[regex]::Unescape()` - what is the reason for calling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether `ConvertTo-Json` puts quotes around a value depends on the type of that value. Strings are put in quotes, other types like Integer or Boolean are not.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> [PSCustomObject]@{'foo'=1} | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "foo":  1
}
PS C:\> [PSCustomObject]@{'foo'='1'} | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "foo":  "1"
}
```

Presumably some of the cells in your Excel sheet contain numbers rather than text (which are then converted accordingly), while the application processing the JSON data expects them to be strings.

I see two ways you could handle this:

- Cast the values to string:

  ```
  $data.parameters.client.value = [string]$ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Value
  ```
- Instead of the property `Value` use the property `Text`, which returns the value of a cell as a string:

  ```
  $data.parameters.client.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Text
  ```